# Checking Model relationships in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model

Is there a way to check CakePHP's model relationships?

One model is saving twice on a table and I really suspect there's something wrong with my relationships. Problem is I have a lot of tables so it's really a pain. I'm wondering if there's a more sure and easy way of doing this maybe automatically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `var_dump` or `print_r` to see what your models look like.  If you want to quickly do it for all models, modify `AppModel` to have it dump the structure when each model loads.

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

        $this->log("Model [{$this->name}] belongsTo = " . print_r($this->belongsTo, true), LOG_DEBUG);
        $this->log("Model [{$this->name}] hasOne = " . print_r($this->hasOne, true), LOG_DEBUG);
        $this->log("Model [{$this->name}] hasMany = " . print_r($this->hasMany, true), LOG_DEBUG);
        $this->log("Model [{$this->name}] hasAndBelongsToMany = " . print_r($this->hasAndBelongsToMany, true), LOG_DEBUG);
    }
}
```